# Xamarin/Android: Location works in emulation but not physical device

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-gps

I'm using Xamarin to build a an Android app that lists a bunch of stores and tells you how far away they are. I already have it working in the Android emulator. But when I debug on my physical device (Samsung Galaxy S5 / LineageOS 15.1 / Android 8.1.0), I don't seem to receive location updates. Other apps that utilize location data work fine, such as Google Maps.

The app asks for permission and I've made sure that the following function, `StartRequestingLocationData()` is indeed being called.

However, `OnLocationChanged(Location location)` never gets called when the app is run on the physical device. In the emulator, everything works fine and it gives the location both immediately at startup and keeps updating it as new location data comes in.

I'd love to provide an error message or be more thorough somehow, but I don't see any clues as to what might be the cause of this. I see no error or warning in the output, for example.

This is my first Android app (although I'm seasoned in many other platforms) so I may very well be missing something that's obvious to others. My problem is that I can't figure out where to look for clues and searching online hasn't yielded coverage of this problem.

Here's the relevant code. Thanks in advance.

```
    public void StartRequestingLocationData()
    {
        this.location_manager = (LocationManager)GetSystemService(Context.LocationService);

        Criteria crit = new Criteria();
        crit.Accuracy = Accuracy.Fine;
        crit.AltitudeRequired = false;
        crit.BearingRequired = false;
        crit.SpeedRequired = false;

        // Both the emulator and physical device report this as "gps".
        string provider = this.location_manager.GetBestProvider(crit, true);

        this.location_manager.RequestLocationUpdates(provider, 1, 1, this);

        Location last_location = this.location_manager.GetLastKnownLocation(provider);
        if (last_location != null)
        {
            this.OnLocationChanged(last_location);
        }
    }

    public void OnLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        foreach (Replenisher store in this.stores)
        {
            if (store.DistanceView != null)
            {
                LatLng store_loc = new LatLng(double.Parse(store.GPSN), double.Parse(store.GPSW));
                LatLng our_loc = new LatLng(location.Latitude, location.Longitude);
                double distance = Meters.ComputeDistanceBetween(our_loc, store_loc);

                store.DistanceView.Text = GetString(
                    Resource.String.kilometers_away,
                    distance / 1000
                );
                store.DistanceView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: So no exception at all? Do you request the permissions correctly?

Comment: No exception at all. No error or warning of any sort. StartRequestLocationData() is only run upon successful granting of permission, so at least the app tells me that I'm requesting, and receiving, the permission correctly. The physical device asks properly and runs the code that should run when permission is given. I just don't receive the location updates themselves.

Comment: Well can't you try on another device? Just to be sure it isnt' the custom rom affecting somehow

Comment: @Teekin Has your location actually changed? Take your device and go for a walk 

Comment: @BrunoCaceiro: People are quick to suggest that the custom ROM is a problem if I mention LineageOS and it never is. It's just Android with all the Google stuff. Could of course be something else specific to the phone. I'd be happy to try on another device though, but I don't have access to one that's new enough for the API I'm using. I'll try getting a hold of one, though. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @SushiHangover: I had tried walking around the house (enough to spot differences in other apps), but now I was going to try again, opened the app and for some reason I see numbers. They're completely out of whack (11-12 **thousand** kilometers off) but they're there! I'm gonna see if I manage to replicate this.

Comment: So the 11-12 thousand "inaccuracy" was just me having put longitude/latitude in the wrong order, so that was easy, but I don't know why I'm getting the numbers on the device now. I really want to be able to replicate this problem. Seems like one of those problems that just need to be talked about. Weird.

Comment: It appears that when I start asking for location data matters more on the phone, i.e., if I ask too soon (before the UI updates), it doesn't give me updates until something changes (and it seems to require more than walking around my house). On the emulator, it seems that there is already some kind of "location cache" or whatever, that tells the apps the location right away and keeps feeding it location updates, even without changes. Does any of that make sense?

Comment: I'm going to try again tomorrow and see if I manage to properly replicate the problem. It appears to have simply gone away. Thanks for the assistance, Bruno and SushiHangover.